# Is it possible to share access to a custom entity record in crm 2011 online?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

In a plugin, I want to grant access to a record of a custom entity. Is this possible? The 2011 sdk seems to suggest that the [GrantAccessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.grantaccessrequest.aspx) class only applies to out of the box entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GrantAccess message is also available for custom entities. See the excel file in the SDK which describes the available messages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx